# Why is this C++ program slower than Node.js equivalent?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14

I'm learning C++ and decided to remake an old Node.js program to see how much faster it would be, as C++ should to my knowledge be a lot faster due to being compiled.

This program is very simple, it is just to find prime numbers. It uses the exact same logic as my Node.js program, but it takes 8 to 9 seconds whereas the Node.js took only 4 to 5 seconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


// Declare functions
int main();
bool isPrime(int num);
bool is6n_1(int num);

// Define variables
int currentNum = 5;         // Start at 5 so we iterate over odd numbers, we add 2 and 3 manually
int primesToFind = 1000000;
int primesFound = 2;
int* primes = NULL;



// Main
int main() {

    // Create dynamic memory primes array
    primes = new int[1000000];
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    cout << "Finding primes..." << endl;
    time_t start_time = time(NULL);


    // Main execution loop
    for (; primesFound < primesToFind; currentNum += 2) {
        if (isPrime(currentNum)) {
            primes[primesFound] = currentNum;
            primesFound++;
        }
    }

    time_t end_time = time(NULL);
    cout << "Finished" << endl;
    cout << end_time - start_time << endl;

    return 0;
}



// Check whether a number is prime
// Dependant on primes[]
bool isPrime(int num) {

    // We divide it by every previous prime number smaller than the sqrt
    // and check the remainder
    for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt(num) && i < primesFound; i++) {       // Start i at 1 to skip the first unnecessary modulo with 2
        if (num % primes[i] == 0) {                                 // because we increment by 2
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Because I'm so new at C++ I don't know if this is due to inefficient code (probably) or because of some settings in the compiler or in Visual Studio IDE.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 community, release version and x64 architecture with O2 optimization.

How can I make this program faster?

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i <= sqrt(num) ...)` `i` is an index. Did you mean `primes[i] <= sqrt(num)`? (Actually, that could be rewritten further to handle some bounds checking and avoid floating point computations, but that would be a major reason this code runs slower than you'd expect.)

Comment: Most of the computation probably goes into calculating `sqrt(num)` for every iteration of the for loop, store the value in a variable outside the loop

Comment: The code has an obvious typo; it makes no sense to check if `i` (an index) is less than the  sqrt of the current candidate, what you wanted was `primes[i] < sqrt(currentNum)`. Note also that it's equivalent but faster to check if `primes[i]*primes[i] < currentNum`.

Comment: @6502 You'd actually want to check `<=` because otherwise you might think `4` or `9` is prime.

Comment: You might also want to show your NodeJS code.

Comment: Also in C++ array indexing starts at `0`, not `1`, so `for(int i = 1; ...)` when `i` is an index is incorrect. In your case it doesn't matter because you only ever call `isPrime` on odd numbers, but your code would incorrectly say `isPrime(4)` is `true`.

Comment: I'm mostly worried about whether that `sqrt()` call gets hoisted out of the loop, and whether it's a `double` comparison every cycle: I don't know whether VS2019 knows it's a pure function or how well it's optimized. Also, how do you even get that without including `<cmath>`?

Comment: Hoisting the `sqrt` or not seems like it will be completely swamped by the loop running way more times than necessary.

Comment: "It uses the exact same logic as my Node.js program" can you show that too?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding compiler settings, I can only say:

- Use x64, not x86 (32-bit) as a target
- Use Release as configuration, not Debug
- Enable aggressive optimizations

(Edit) It seems you already have these settings in the compiler, so there should be nothing obvious left to do regarding the compiler.

Also, there is probably a lot of optimization possible, because it does not seem that you are using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. You can then further skip all multiples of two, and increase the step size to tree.

And you would of course have to provide the node.js code. I am almost certain that it does not use the **exact** same logic.

Comment: All of your suggestions regarding compiler optimizations are already in effect according to the asker, and the asker _is_ using the sieve of eratosthenes. I'm also not sure that increasing the step size from 2 to 3 actually works correctly. You'd start unnecessarily testing a bunch of even numbers in that case and skipping over twin primes.

Comment: @NathanPierson in my opinion, they are not using the sieve correctly. They check prime numbers every time, instead of crossing out all the multiples of a prime, once they found one. Just because they limit the upper bound to the sqrt of the target number, doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Good point on the difference between trial division and the actual sieve.